# IsPostBack is always = false and request.QueryString is null

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I was wonder why the IsPostBack always give me false and can not get value from Request.QueryString. Do i miss out any part of code?

My JS

```
function BtnCal()
{
    $.post(missingkids_handler,
        {"Action":"MainAct", "SubAction":"SubAct"},
             function(response)
             {
                var rtnObj = response.Data;
                alert(rtnObj);
                $("#retnTxt").html(rtnObj);
             }, "json"); 

}
```

My handler aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Request.QueryString["Action"] != "" && Request.QueryString["Action"] == "MainAct")
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["SubAction"] == "SubAct")
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Write("Hello Here");
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
```

Is simple, that i just want to return a string from handle.aspx while JS call

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it better to use .asmx web-service for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guest, you are using a POST and not GET method, your data are not in the query string. Try using `Request.Form`

```
if (Request.Form["Action"] != "" && Request.Form["Action"] == "MainAct")
```

Comment: I actually i had include this at my JS

Comment: var missingkids_handler = "MissingKids_handle.aspx";

Answer (score 0):

Use `Request.Form` instead of `Request.QueryString`. It may help you.